# Create my own icon font .ttf .eot .woff and svg files

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons, icon-fonts

I have created some icons in AI, so now I'm looking how to convert them in an icon font for web without using third-party applications (like fontastic...)

So I need to create my own .ttf, .eot, .woff and .svg files to insert them in this way:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "MYFONT";
  src:url("fonts/MYFONT.eot");
  src:url("fonts/MYFONT.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("fonts/MYFONT.woff") format("woff"),
    url("fonts/MYFONT.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("fonts/MYFONT.svg#MYFONT") format("svg");
}
```

Any help will be very useful...  :)

Comment: No you don't: don't use all the obsolete and system formats. [Just use WOFF](http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff) and you're done. Microsoft no longer supports any browsers that don't support WOFF, so EOT is now a dead format; SVG *is literally dead*, the spec was abandoned. TTF and OTF are universal fonts, so browsers may parse them way stricter than *the same font wrapped in WOFF*. Bottom line: in 2016, use WOFF, and only WOFF. Added bonus: your code is cleaner and easier to debug when things go wrong.

Answer (score 11):

I use the **[Icomoon App](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select)**.

The Icomoon App allows you to do each of the following :

- Get one or more icons from several popular icon fonts
- Upload other fonts, which may be icon fonts but also regular fonts
- Upload SVG files to use as icons
- Combine any number of icons from any number of available fonts
- Set the UNICODE hex value for whichever characters you need
- Export and/or save the font set you create

[image: Icomoon]

Comment: This is brilliant. Takes 5 minutes to learn their interface and you import your existing icons, manipulate them, then export them.