# How to make custom icons in css?

Tags: css, icons

I want to make my own icons in CSS. I don't want to use any library like font awesome. I want to make my own icons like font awesome does by CSS. I don't want to use any kind of image.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you need to create your own font https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945370/create-my-own-icon-font-ttf-eot-woff-and-svg-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Fontastic](https://fontastic.me/).  You just create your icons, upload and then you source it from their CDN.  Easy.